# How to add computation on a product attribute in magento admin

Tags: product, admin, product-attribute

Anyone can help me achieve my query? I'm no expert in magento but I know php conditions but I don't know how to apply my need in magento. I'm thinking of using attributes because I believe there is no other solution. So here it goes:

In magento admin product page, I want to add manually cost price attribute, shipping cost attribute, and total cost attribute, but Total Cost automated, it should have a computation wherein it will add cost price and shipping cost. Then lastly, auto computation for the Profit attribute, where it will calculate, Selling price (Default Product price attribute) minus Total Cost divide by Selling price.

Looking forward to hear from all the magento ninja. Thank you!

---

So far this is what I've done based on the Module Tutorial Link given by @Sander. And followed the code of @Andarsh

in config.xml

```
    <modules>
    <ProfitAndTotalCost_ProfitAndTotalComputation>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </ProfitAndTotalCost_ProfitAndTotalComputation>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <ProfitAndTotalCost_ProfitAndTotalComputation>
            <class>ProfitAndTotalCost_ProfitAndTotalComputation_Model</class>
        </ProfitAndTotalCost_ProfitAndTotalComputation>
    </models>

    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <profitandtotalcost_profitandtotalcomputation>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>profitandtotalcost_profitandtotalcomputation/observer</class>
                    <method>addCostAndShipping</method>
                </profitandtotalcost_profitandtotalcomputation>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>      
    </events>
</global>
```

For the Observer.php

```
class ProfitAndTotalCost_ProfitAndTotalComputation_Model_Observer
{
    public function addCostAndShipping($observer)
    {
       $product = $observer->getProduct();
       $cost_price = $product->getAttributeText('cost');
       $shipping_cost = $product->getAttributeText('supp_main_landed_cost');

       $total_cost = $cost_price + $shipping_cost;

       //save to total cost
       $product->setTotalCostMain($total_cost)->save();
       Mage::log($product->getId() . " - ".$product->getTotalCostMain(), null, 'custom_log.log'); //create a file in /var/log folder
    }   
}
```

This is my module: ProfitAndTotalCost_ProfitAndTotalComputation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ProfitAndTotalCost_ProfitAndTotalComputation>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </ProfitAndTotalCost_ProfitAndTotalComputation>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: You will have to create a module with all your business logic. Check this: http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/

Comment: Can you walk me thru? Basic would help. Thanks!

Comment: @KiD Cajes , what you need to do is just write a small javascript for your admin side, what that will do is once you put in values into the cost fields, it will auto-populate the selling and profit fields, rest when you save the product the values would get saved., hope this should guide you in right direction, for more details let me know

Comment: --AdarshKhatri --huzefam thank you for the inputs but I'm no code expert I'm just a user with a very super minimal code knowledge (acquired by youtube :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, if I understand your requirement you could do this way:

Create 3 attributes- `cost_price, shipping_cost and total_cost`.

Now have a observer to add `cost_price` and `shipping_cost` and fetch to `total_cost`.

Your observer:

```
public function addCostAndShipping($observer)
{
   $product = $observer->getProduct();
   $cost_price = $product->getCostPrice();
   $shipping_cost = $product->getShippingCost();

   $total_cost = $cost_price + $shipping_cost;

   //save to total cost
   $product->setTotalCostMain($total_cost);
   Mage::log($product->getId() . " - ".$product->getTotalCostMain(), null, 'custom_log.log'); //create a file in /var/log folder
}
```

In your config.xml

```
<global>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <yourmodule>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                    <method>addCostAndShipping</method>
                </yourmodule>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>      
    </events>
</global>
```

**How it will work**

When you enter `cost_price` and `shipping_cost` and save the product, before saving it magento will add them both and save it to your another attribute `total_cost`.

**[Update]**

change your config.xml

```
<global>
    <models>
        <profitandtotalcost_profitandtotalcomputation>
       <class>ProfitAndTotalCost_ProfitAndTotalComputation_Model</class>
        </profitandtotalcost_profitandtotalcomputation>
    </models>

    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <profitandtotalcost_profitandtotalcomputation_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>profitandtotalcost_profitandtotalcomputation/observer</class>
                    <method>addCostAndShipping</method>
                </profitandtotalcost_profitandtotalcomputation_observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>      
    </events>
</global>
```

**[Update 2]**

Your folder/file structure as per your settings:

```
app/code/local/ProfitAndTotalCost/ProfitAndTotalComputation/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/ProfitAndTotalCost/ProfitAndTotalComputation/Model/Observer.php
//**Capital and small letter combination should be same as specified in config.xml**
```

**Update 3**

Your observer

```
class ProfitAndTotalCost_ProfitAndTotalComputation_Model_Observer
{
    public function addCostAndShipping($observer)
    {
       $product = $observer->getProduct();
       $cost_price = $product->getCostPrice();
       $shipping_cost = $product->getShippingCost();

       $total_cost = $cost_price + $shipping_cost;

       //save to total cost
       $product->setTotalCostMain($total_cost);

       Mage::log($product->getId() . " - ".$product->getTotalCostMain(), null, 'custom_log.log'); //create a file in /var/log folder
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'll read on module and try your code. Cause I don't know the steps on how and where to put this codes of yours. Thanks

Comment: $product->getAttributeText('shipping_cost');  ---- is this the attribute code or the attribute label?

Comment: Att code. They should be exactly same as when you created them.

Comment: $product->setTotalCost($total_cost)->save(); ------- the total cost attribute code I use is total_cost_main, how do I use it in your code?

Comment: $product->seTotalCostMain($total_cost)->save().

Comment: I tried but didn't work

Comment: Make sure your observer working (check if it is creating a file called `custom_log.log` in `/var/log` folder and also hope your attributes are set to used for all kind of products.

Comment: yes attribute are for all kind of products and there's no folder /var/log

Comment: sorry it should be `$product->setTotalCostMain($total_cost)->save()`, I had type.

Comment: I'm sorry but I did managed to check the typo, but still not working

Comment: Sure, can you add all the code what have you done so far in your question please. And also there should be folder in your root directory `/var/log`.

Comment: Updated my question and pasted the codes

Comment: check my update. If it is not creating file `var/log/custom_log.log` then its not calling observer function.

Comment: I tried but still the same, I even set the Log settings into YES, but still the same

Comment: Just to confirm, do you have these lines in your config.xml? At beginning of file `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>` and at the end `</config>

Comment: Yes I do, but here is the a portion of the system.log:

2015-09-09T09:59:14+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Profitandtotalcost/Profitandtotalcomputation/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/XXXXX/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Comment: And also I found this one:

2015-09-09T09:59:14+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Profitandtotalcost/Profitandtotalcomputation/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/XXXXX/public_html/app/code/local:/home/XXXXX/public_html/app/code/community:/home/XXXX/public_html/app/code/core:/home/XXXX/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/XXXX/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Comment: This error tells me that magento is not finding your observer. Can you tell me where have you put your file? `app/code/community/....then what`? Remember your folder naming of Namespace and Module name should be exact same `[cpaital/small letter matter]` as you have in config.xml.

Comment: In your case it should be `app/code/community/ProfitAndTotalCost/ProfitAndTotalComputation`.

Comment: It's in app/code/local and yes I believed its properly named. See my update

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: And also are you still getting that error in log?

Comment: No more error on the log, but I have this one 
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/XXXXXXXX/public_html/app/code/local/ProfitAndTotalCost/ProfitAndTotalComputation/Model/Observer.php, line 16

Comment: alright, just comment out that `Mage::log` line.

Comment: Commented out, but when I tried saving the product, there is no computation and same error

Comment: Do you have multi store as well?

Comment: Yes, but currently disabled

Comment: Check update 3 please.

Comment: I tried bu the Same error I'm facing

Comment: One last qst, did you assign those 3 attributes to `attribute_set` as well?

Comment: Yes I did, but the same

Comment: You will have to debug step by step, first remove all code and just add `Mage::log("ya ya", null, 'custom_log.log')` in observer function, if this creates file successfully then it is calling your observer, then you can investigate further. Good luck

Comment: Thanks but, I think its the cache, it's not reflecting the changes, I tried clearing the cache and flushing every cache, tried to logout/in then same error appears. Any other means of clearing my cache specially for the Admin Panel?

Comment: Disable your module and then check if that error still presents, that means error is caused by something else.

Comment: It displays "ya ya" in the custom_log.log

Comment: So observer is working, put all code back and check each line.

Comment: fatal error maximum execution time

Comment: Ok, seems like no error this time but there's no computation that is happening.

Comment: Alright, I have updated the answer, and have tested on my server too. Should work. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The `catalog_product_save_before` event is probably what you are looking for. It' s fired every time a product is saved, giving you the chance to change data before it's actually saved in the database

In your modules `config.xml`

```
<global>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <[namespace]_[module]_catalog_product_save_before>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>catalogProductSaveBefore</method>
                </[namespace]_[module]_catalog_product_save_before>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

in the `Observer.php`

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
    public function catalogProductSaveBefore($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        $cost = // calculate your cost here
        $product->setCost($cost);

        // and so on for all attributes you want to fill

        return $this;
    }
}
```

More on building a module here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/basics-creating-magento-module/

Comment: wow, I didn't expect this to be that complicated. Where do I exactly find this files?

Comment: @KiDCajes in that case please follow the tutorial about module creation first. Then the observer should explain itself

Comment: i guess we can simply do this in admin itself without going into the observer loop, just put in a basic javascript, which populates the cost and profit fields, and once you click on product save, fields are saved, extra benefit , admin knows what would be values of those attributes before he finally does a save

Comment: @SanderMangel I will proof read the tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: @huzefam can you show me how to do your solution?

Comment: @KiDCajes place that one under his question ;)

Comment: @KiDCajes yes provided an answer

Answer (score 0):

Create one js file, say `cost.js`

You can place the file in `{{root_dir}}/js/cost.js`

In cost.js (i am assuming you have included a jquery file)

```
jQuery('#shipping_cost').keyup(function() {
        var shipping_cost = parseInt(jQuery(this).val());
        var cost = jQuery('#cost').val();
        var total_cost = cost + shipping_cost
        jQuery('#total_cost').val(total_cost);
    });
```

Include this file, by creating a local.xml in

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/
<layout>
     <adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
            <reference name="head">

                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>
       <action method="addJs"><script>cost.js</script></action>      
            </reference>
        </adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
</layout>
```

So you should have you values populated once admin fills in the above two fields, you can proceed same for profit calculation.

Comment: I'll try this one and get back to you.

Comment: where do i get this neo/tax.js

Comment: sorry my bad, edited