# calculate shipping price and write value in attribute after save product page

Tags: magento-1.9, php, attributes, shipping, backend

Each product have a addiotinal attribute "shipping_cost".
In magento admin product page i add the product weight in the "weight" attribute.

```
[weight] * shipping_rate = [shipping_cost]
```

After i click the product save button i need a function to calculate the shipping cost and write the result in the "shipping_cost" attribute based on the product weight.

For example: If the product weight is 3,20kgs the automated calculation is:

```
3,20kgs * 6,50 Euro = 20,80 Euro.
```

The script need to write the result (20,80) in the shipping_cost attribute.

We have diffrent shipping rates:

```
Up to 1kgs -> 4,90 Euro
From 1kgs to 3kgs -> 5,50 Euro
From 3kgs to  5kgs -> 6,50 Euro
From 5kgs to 10kgs -> 7,90 Euro
From 10kgs to 20kgs -> 10,50 Euro
From 20kgs to 31,50kgs -> 13,90 Euro
```

Do you have a idea how i can solve this problem?

Similar question i found:
[How to add computation on a product attribute in magento admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82395/how-to-add-computation-on-a-product-attribute-in-magento-admin)

Update:
Now i found a solution for press "save" button in the product edit mask.
But this dont run with product mass action under the product grid.
Do you have a idea how i can add a extra entry in the mass dropdown in the product grid?

**Update**

No i create a solution that only works in the product edit mask if i use the product save button. What i have to change to make my script also run with mass actions from the product grid? How i can create a extra entry in the dropdown for mass action in the product grid and add my script to them?

data.php

```
<?php
class Wmkosc_Productcost_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Wmkosc_Productcost>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Wmkosc_Productcost>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <productcost>
        <class>Wmkosc_Productcost_Helper</class>
      </productcost>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <productcost>
        <class>Wmkosc_Productcost_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>productcost_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </productcost>
    </models>
    <events>
      <catalog_product_save_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <catalog_product_save_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>productcost/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>updateShippingCost</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </catalog_product_save_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

observer.php:

```
<?php
class Wmkosc_Productcost_Model_Observer{
    public function updateShippingCost(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $_pro = $observer->getProduct();  
        $weight = $_pro->getWeight();
        if($weight < 1){
            $shipcost = '4.9';
        } elseif($weight < 3){
            $shipcost = '5.5';
        } elseif($weight < 5){
            $shipcost = '6.5';
        } elseif($weight < 10){
            $shipcost = '7.9';
        } elseif($weight < 20){
            $shipcost = '10.5';
        } elseif($weight < 31.5){
            $shipcost = '13.9';
        } else{
            $shipcost = '';
        }
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_pro->getId());
        $_product->setData('versandkosten_de',$shipcost);
        $_product->getResource()->saveAttribute($_product,'versandkosten_de');
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite observer from your config.xml `catalog_product_save_before`:

```
<events>
   <catalog_product_save_before>
      <observers>
         <module_name>
           <class>model_name/observer</class>
           <method>catalog_product_save_before</method>
         </module_name>
      </observers>
   </catalog_product_save_before>
</events>
```

then create observer.php file inside Model folder of your module:

class MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Observer {

```
public function catalog_product_save_before($observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();

    //write your calculation here
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This works only if i push the save button in the product edit mask.

Comment: How i can run your observe/function when i use a mass action in the drop down from the product grid?

Comment: I update my question with a solution and next question

Comment: @Tommy , You can try to use **catalog_product_attribute_update_before** event. May be this event can help you to update attribute value on mass action.